# Build option for windows is not showing in android studio

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-release

I am in the latest stable release for flutter desktop and have installed Visual Studio 2022 but still the option for "Windows" is not showing.
Do i still need to run the below command in stable release?

```
flutter config --enable-<windows>-desktop
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try its working fine

```
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
flutter config --enable-windows-uwp-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it needs to press the previous and Then the next button.

[image]